# Написать программу, управляющую работой библиотеки. Создать классы: «Книга», «Отдел», «Библиотека»

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ооп, наследование

Написать программу, управляющую работой библиотеки. Создать классы: «Книга», «Отдел», «Библиотека». В классах реализовать следующие функции: добавление, удаление книг из отделов, выдача книг на абонемент. Классы должны содержать методы доступа и изменения всех полей.
Важна любая помощь! Не могу понять как реализовать добавление отделов, а в эти отделы книги. И потом посмотреть в какие книги в определенном отделе. Да  суть наследования я тут как-то не очень уловил..
Буду рад любой подсказке!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class book {
public:
    string name;
    string author;
    void see() {
    
    }
    void set_name() {
        cout << "Введите название книги: ";
        cin >> name;
    }
    void set_author() {
        cout << "Введите автора: ";
        cin >> author;
    }
    string get_name() {
        return name;
    }
    string get_author() {
        return author;
    }
};

class otdel:public book {
public:
    book arr_of_books[10];
    string nameOfOtdel;
    int number_of_book = 0;
    void add() {
        if (number_of_book + 1 <= 10) {
            number_of_book++;
            cout << "Введите данные новой книги\n\n";
            cout << "Название: ";
            cin >> arr_of_books[number_of_book - 1].name;
            cout << "Автор: ";
            cin >> arr_of_books[number_of_book - 1].author;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Новая книга успешно добавлена!" << endl;
        }
        else cout << "Недостаточно памяти для добавления нового объекта!" << endl << endl;
    }
    void del() {
        int number_of_deleted_item;
        cout << "Введите номер удаляемой записи: ";
        cin >> number_of_deleted_item;
        number_of_deleted_item--;
            for (int i = number_of_deleted_item; i < number_of_book- 1; i++)
                arr_of_books[i] = arr_of_books[i + 1];
            number_of_book--;
        cout << "Запись удалена!" << endl << endl;
    }
    void see() {
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_book; i++) {
            cout << arr_of_books[i].name << " " << arr_of_books[i].author << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    string get_nameOfOtdel() {
        return nameOfOtdel;
    }
};


class library :public otdel {
    otdel arr_of_otdel[10];
    string nameOfLibrary;
    int numberOfOtdel = 0;
public:
    void set_nameOfLibrary() {
        cout << "Название библиотеки: ";
        cin >> nameOfLibrary;
    }

    string get_nameOfLibrary() {
        return nameOfLibrary;
    }
    void addOtdel() {
        if (numberOfOtdel + 1 <= 10) {
            numberOfOtdel++;
            cout << "Название отделa: ";
            cin >> arr_of_otdel[numberOfOtdel - 1].nameOfOtdel;
            cout << "Новый отдел успешно добавлен!" << endl;
        }
        else cout << "Недостаточно памяти для добавления нового объекта!" << endl << endl;
    }
    void delOtdel() {
        int number_of_deleted_otdel;
        cout << "Введите номер удаляемой записи: ";
        cin >> number_of_deleted_otdel;
        number_of_deleted_otdel--;
        for (int i = number_of_deleted_otdel; i < numberOfOtdel - 1; i++)
            arr_of_otdel[i] = arr_of_otdel[i + 1];
        numberOfOtdel--;
        cout << "Отдел удален!" << endl << endl;
    }
    void see() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOtdel; i++) {
            cout << arr_of_otdel[i].nameOfOtdel << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int kod;
    library n1;
    otdel n2;
    n1.set_nameOfLibrary();
    n1.get_nameOfLibrary();
    do {
        cout << "1. Добавить книгу" << endl;
        cout << "2. Удалить книгу" << endl;
        cout << "5. Просмотр" << endl;
        cout << "0. Выход" << endl;
        cin >> kod;
        switch (kod) {
        case 1: n2.add();  break;
        case 2: n2.del(); break;
        //case 3: n1.; break;
        //case 4: n1.delOtdel(); break;
        case 5: n2.see(); break;
        case 0: exit(0);
        }
    } while (kod != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я думаю структура проекта неправильна, представь библиотеку в реальной жизни. В библиотеке есть отделы, а в отделе уже книги. И ты добавляешь книгу не в книгу, ну или по крайней мере не используешь для этого другие книги, как ты делаешь в функция add, del, see. Ты книги добавляешь в отделе и там же удаляешь, так что только там и реализуй их. А у книги есть, только название книги, имя автора и все что ты можешь сделать это узнать название книги, имя автора, посмотреть на нее в целом, ну в жизни вряд ли можешь устанавливать нового автора и название книги, но если надо, то оставь.

Comment: А вот в отделе у нас есть список книг, которые в нем хранятся и название отдела, и мы можем добавлять и удалять книги из отдела. Так что все связанное с именами авторов и названиями убери. Вообще я не понимаю зачем тут наследование, если между ними нет ничего общего.

Comment: И последнее библиотека, в ней уже содержится список отделов, название библиотеки, и в ней так же можно реализовать добавление отделов изменение названий отделов и тд. А насчет выдачи абонемента я лично не очень понял как это реализовать, но проведи ассоциацию с реальной жизнью.

Comment: Вот примерная архитектура проекта: https://pastebin.com/Wbz2ZH9L
эта структура без учета мелочей всяких

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/composite